# Unsupported resolution when connected with HDMI

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

So here's the situation. One day my Acer Aspire One 725 fell and its display isn't working anymore. However, I got a display workaround by the means of HDMI cable connected to my TV(max supported resolution is 1920x1080. That's how I ran Windows 10, for example. Today I installed Xubuntu 15.10 and while setting up my displays(turning off the broken laptop display), I made a slight mistake. I set the resolution to 1440x900 which is perfectly fine with refresh rate of 75 Hz. However, I mistakenly changed the refresh rate to 59 Hz and TV immediately blacked out, saying sth like "This video mode is not supported, change your resolution". I'm able to get into xubuntu's recovery mode. How can I undo/reset these changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just installed today, it might be easier to just do a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

might this help ? even re installing might be simpler incase you want to try some deeper digging. either is good i think

https://www.debian-administration.org/article/201/Changing_X11_resolution_on_the_fly